# solr not return any results? anyone please explain this xml reponse?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am trying to fetch the results after indexing some data. But when I make the search it doesn't returns any results.

anyone can Please explain where I am going wrong. Enabling the debugQuery=true&indent=true gives the following output.

```
 This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response> 
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
<lst name="highlighting"/>
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">java</str>
<str name="querystring">java</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
+DisjunctionMaxQuery((shortname:java^5.0 | fullname:java^40.0)~0.01)    DisjunctionMaxQuery((fullname:java^2.0)~0.01)
</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">
+(shortname:java^5.0 | fullname:java^40.0)~0.01 (fullname:java^2.0)~0.01
</str>
<lst name="explain"/>
<str name="QParser">DisMaxQParser</str>
<null name="altquerystring"/>
<null name="boostfuncs"/>
<lst name="timing">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
<lst name="prepare">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>  
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="process">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent"> 
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

This is how my Schema Looks :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <schema name="example" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_lws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"    generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" /> 
</types>


<fields>
```

```
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 <defaultSearchField>fullname</defaultSearchField>
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

</schema>
```

Comment: Which version are you using and what type of analyzers are on the field shortname and fullname?

Comment: Need more info - what does your schema and fieldtypes look like?

Comment: I just added the Schema file please have a look Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field type for both the fields `fullname` and `shortname` are string.
From the field definition of `string` no analysis is being performed on this field.
So the search term should be the exact case and match for the field to be returned.

Change the field type to `text` and reindex the contents to check the search.